# $f$ smooth non-analytic, $f(0) = 0$. Is $f(x)/x$ smooth at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

I'd like to know if the following statement is true:

For any $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0) = 0$, then $f(x)/x$ is smooth at $0$.

- if $f$ is analytic, then this is clear by simply Taylor-expanding it.
- hence, my question is for when $f$ is non-analytic. I am hoping that, maybe the fact that derivatives of $f$ look bizarre means that there won't be a singularity at $0$, even after dividing by $x$. (Which seems to be the case for the prototypical example of smooth but non-analytic function, the $\exp(-1/x)$ example).

I wonder if this can be done through some sort of polynomial approximation scheme, but am not at all versed in the topic.

---

It is a very bizarre question, and I am not *a priori* convinced it is true. However, this result seems to be used in a paper I am reading. Indeed:

I am working in the space of germs $\mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ at $0$, which I treat as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. I consider the subspace:

$V =$ {$ax + K |  a \in \mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}), K \in \mathbb{R}$} $\subset \mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

They claim, in Example 2 of §1 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243097390_An_Introduction_to_Catastrophe_Theory_and_Its_Applications) (whose DOI you might find useful if you want to download it; but they do not say much more), that $\dim_\mathbb{R}(\mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})/V) = 0$, which seems to imply that $V = \mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Which in turn seems to indicate that any germ in $\mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ can be written in the form of an element of $V$.

It is clearly true that any *analytic* germ can be put in this form. But since there definitely exist non-analytic germs, I don't see why that statement would hold; unless the question I asked holds.

Indeed, if for every non-analytic function $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$, we have that $f(x)/x$ is smooth at $0$, then this allows us to put any germ $f \in \mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ in the form $f(x) = x \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} + f(0)$, so that $f \in V$ as required.

Hence: is this true?

Comment: To clarify an issue from a previous comment: The issue isn't "is it defined at $0$?" and it definitely won't have an analytic continuation since $f$ isn't analytic.  Rather, the question is "If $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $f(0)=0$, and $$g(x) = \begin{cases}f(x)/x, & x \neq 0\\ f'(0), & x = 0\end{cases},$$ then is $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? – [Taylor's Theorem Application Question, $f(x)$ smooth and $f(0)=0$ implies $f(x)/x$ smooth.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/285650/42969)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3276553/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350284/42969

Comment: @MartinR these do indeed answer my question, thank you very much! :) Do you want to post these as an answer, or should I close the question?